# cannot boot into ubuntu... goes to black screen right after loading initial ramdisk

Tags: boot, grub2

Got a Dell Inspiron 13 7000 Laptop, it had a windows 10 on it, I installed ubuntu alongside windows (which I had done several times before on other laptops without any problems) and the windos didnt start anymore. namely when I chose windows on grub, it went on a black screen, the laptop stayed on (with keyboard LEDs on) but only with that **black screen without any words,etc.**

I thought it must be windows's fault and left it, I worked with ubuntu after a few days the same happened with ubuntu: when I chose ubuntu in grub it went to a black screen blah blah blah... 
I again said it must be because of the windows so this time I formatted the entire hard disk and installed a fresh ubuntu... (the latest official 17.10 on this website) it worked for a few days (nearly one week which took me to install my favourite apps and customize everything) and today the same happened again!

when I try to boot ubuntu on **recovery mode**, choosing the option in grub leads to only two lines of codes. **right after it says "loading initial ramdisk" it goes on the black screen with LEDs on keyboard on but nothing happes until I force turn off holding down the power key**. 
is that a known issue? somebody else faced this? any workaround? it is really not a good choice to reinstall ubuntu each time and customize it gaain and download all the apps, bla bla bla... that is the only thing I know works for me now

forgot to say that even after this happened live usb can boot ubuntu from the usb but not from the hard disk

Comment: I experience the same on ubuntu 18.04!

Comment: I just boot-repair to fix that, 

use a live ubuntu, connect to internet, open a terminal (ctrl-alt-t) and type:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

then install boot-repair using:

sudo apt install boot-repair

then launch boot-repair fo to advanced options and try to fix the problem (I could do that by purging grub and reinstalling it with a nomodset option)

Comment: My case was due to unsupported Ryzen APU on the default kernel. Kernel upgrade fixed it!